# How do you print "%" in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to make the % sign appear in the front end, but nothing is showing up. I've tried escaping the characters, but still doesn't work.

```
this.symbolType == "%";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `label` then just do like this.You don't need to pass it from the `.ts` file.Just do it directly inside the `html` page.

```
 <ion-label>%</ion-label>
```

**Update:** You don't need to give `this`.Use as shown below.

```
<ion-label> {{symbolType}} </ion-label>
```

[**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hGf1R3?p=preview)

Comment: Yes I'm using it as a label but the label is dynamic, so it looks something like this: 

`<ion-label> {{this.symbolType}} </ion-label>`

Comment: Is this `this.symbolType` change time to time according to the different scenario?

Comment: Yes it changes based on a ion-select

Comment: please see the **Update** of my answer.

Comment: Omg I just noticed whats wrong, I put 2 equal signs instead of just 1

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to use its Entity. percent symbol is `&#37;` Read more here http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

```
this.symbolType = '%';
this.htmlEntity = this.symbolType.replace('%', '&#37;');
```